# django modeltranslation - default field?

Tags: django, internationalization

Django's modeltranslation app is generally a fantastic tool for internationalization. There is, however, one thing that bugs me. When I define my set of languages, modeltranslation generates n fields, one per language. The problem is, I end up with a redundant field (my default language is english).

So I have:

field
field_en
field_fr
field_jp

And field == field_en. Am I misusing modeltranslation, or is there some way to fix this?

EDIT: So to clarify, I'd like to get rid of either field or field_en.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you missed the [Rules for translated field access](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/wiki/InstallationAndUsage#Rules_for_translated_field_access) in docs, and if you want to remove the main field in admin then see section [Django admin backend integration](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/wiki/InstallationAndUsage#Django_admin_backend_integration).

And in template file you just have to write the main field like this way

```
{{obj.field}}
```

if your current locale is English it will copy the `field_en` to `field` and same for the other languages.